# Show that ON-sequence is a base

Tags: hilbert-spaces, orthonormal

I have a Hilbert space $H$ and a base $(e_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ and a ON-sequence $(f_n)_{n=1}^\infty$.

Given
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty ||e_n - f_n||^2 < 1
$$
show that $(f_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ is a base.

My work:
It is straight forward to rewrite the sum
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty (1 - \langle e_n, f_n\rangle) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \langle e_n, e_n - f_n\rangle) < \frac12
$$
and it also holds for each $n$
$$
\langle e_n, f_n\rangle > \frac12
$$

I then I have tried to show by contradiction by assuming there is a non-zero vector $a$ that is orthogonal to $f_n$:
Assume there is a vector $a$ s.t $||a|| = 1$ and $\langle a, f_n\rangle = 0$ for all $n$.
$$
\langle a, f_n \rangle = \langle \sum_{m=1}^\infty\langle a, e_m\rangle e_m, \sum_{k=1}^\infty\langle f_n, e_k \rangle e_k \rangle = \sum_{m=1}^\infty \langle a, e_m\rangle \langle f_n, e_m \rangle = ...
$$
and I want to somehow show that this is $> 0$ for a contradiction, based on the given inequality.

Am I no the right track? I'm just treading water right now and end up rewriting all the expressions in different ways without progress.

Hints are appreciated (note the homework tag)

Comment: If $(f_n)$ is not a basis, then there exists a normalized $u$ such that $\sum_n |<f_n,u>|^2 < \sum_n |<e_n,u>|^2 = 1$.

Comment: @SimenK. From $||e_n - f_n|| < 1$, though it wasn't a useful property either way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: $$\left|\langle a,e_n \rangle\right| = \left|\langle a, e_n - f_n \rangle \right| \le \|a\| \|e_n - f_n\|$$
Now use the given inequality...

Comment: That made it to easy!